# ->find($id) in entity returns an empty proxy object symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm doing a search on an entity, but this returns me a proxy object. Thus I am trying to do the search.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$tipou = $em->getRepository('SertecomvendoautosBundle:TipoUsuario')->find(5);
```

In the database, table tipo_usuario I have only two records with ID 4 and 5, but to make the search with ID 4, doctrine returns the object for me and not the proxy object that returns me with ID 5.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$tipou = $em->getRepository('SertecomvendoautosBundle:TipoUsuario')->find(4);
```

This brings the object in the normal way.

Really do not understand this behavior that doctrine, I would like to know what happens with this.

This is code of entity tipo_usuario.

```
class TipoUsuario {
/**
 * @var string $tipouNombre
 */
private $tipouNombre;

/**
 * @var string $tipouToken
 */
private $tipouToken;

/**
 * @var datetime $tipouCreatedAt
 */
private $tipouCreatedAt;

/**
 * @var datetime $tipouUpdatedAt
 */
private $tipouUpdatedAt;

/**
 * @var integer $tipouId
 */
private $tipouId;


/**
 * Set tipouNombre
 *
 * @param string $tipouNombre
 */
public function setTipouNombre($tipouNombre)
{
    $this->tipouNombre = $tipouNombre;
}

/**
 * Get tipouNombre
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTipouNombre()
{
    return $this->tipouNombre;
}

/**
 * Set tipouToken
 *
 * @param string $tipouToken
 */
public function setTipouToken($tipouToken)
{
    $this->tipouToken = $tipouToken;
}

/**
 * Get tipouToken
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTipouToken()
{
    return $this->tipouToken;
}

/**
 * Set tipouCreatedAt
 *
 * @param datetime $tipouCreatedAt
 */
public function setTipouCreatedAt($tipouCreatedAt)
{
    $this->tipouCreatedAt = $tipouCreatedAt;
}

/**
 * Get tipouCreatedAt
 *
 * @return datetime 
 */
public function getTipouCreatedAt()
{
    return $this->tipouCreatedAt;
}

/**
 * Set tipouUpdatedAt
 *
 * @param datetime $tipouUpdatedAt
 */
public function setTipouUpdatedAt($tipouUpdatedAt)
{
    $this->tipouUpdatedAt = $tipouUpdatedAt;
}

/**
 * Get tipouUpdatedAt
 *
 * @return datetime 
 */
public function getTipouUpdatedAt()
{
    return $this->tipouUpdatedAt;
}

/**
 * Get tipouId
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getTipouId()
{
    return $this->tipouId;
}
```

Comment: please, can you provide the code of your `SertecomvendoautosBundle:TipoUsuario` entity?

Comment: You see that's a proxy doing a var_dump right? Even if you get a proxy you should be able to use your getter and setter as if it was your entity. Did you try to use it as your entity?